# How to choose a specialization for trooper

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I am in the starting zone and level 11 but can't seem to find the specialization trainer that should be available at level 10.

**Where do I find the specialization trainer for troopers?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so training isn't available in starting map, what you need to do is to finish all missions in the starting area and the you will be offered to fly to `Republic fleet` oce you there exit the Arrivals Hangar and you should see a guy named `Captain Jefris` After speaking to him you should be able to get the mission `Advanced Training:Trooper` and should be able to follow it through by opening map, the way you usually do missions.

Here's a video of the guy you need to speak to:

Comment: Since a few patches ago, you should get a pop up to choose a specialization when you reach level 10, no matter where you are.. The trainers have become obsolete if i remember correctly

Comment: @Vahx Except for initial skills.  If it's a power you don't already have, they still have to teach it to you.

Comment: @Frank these are different trainers you are mentioning, skill/power trainers can be found on every planet. The advanced class trainers are the npc's that are next to the skill trainers on the fleet.

Comment: @Vahx Are they?  It's been a while since I've had to use those.  I don't recall having to use them.

Comment: @Frank If my memory serves me right; i uninstalled the game a month or so ago, so i cannot log in to provide proof. Last time i leveled a new character was in august. - Advanced trainers became obsolete when they changed the skill tree's to the discipline system. Skill trainers are needed to acquire new skills and upgrade older ones but the fee was removed.